# Eclipse JNI fails with 'javac: invalid flag: ../bin'

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, javac

I'm trying to create a JNI project in Eclipse using CDT. I'm following [this tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/javanativeinterface.html).

So first I created my project as a Java project and created a `HelloJNI` class in the default package, which contains some really basic code.

I then added a C nature to my project, selecting 'Makefile Project' in 'Project type' and 'Linux GCC' in 'Toolchains'.

Then I created a new directory called 'jni' to store all the C code. I then created a new file in eclipse called 'makefile' (note the lowercase name) and added this to it.

```
# Define a variable for classpath
CLASS_PATH = ../bin

# Define a virtual path for .class in the bin directory
vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)

# $* matches the target filename without the extension
HelloJNI.h : HelloJNI.class
    javac -h -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*
```

I then created a build target called 'HelloJNI.h' in the jni folder, which automatically used the makefile. I then attempted to build the target, but I got this error:

```
javac -h -classpath ../bin HelloJNI
javac: invalid flag: ../bin
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
make: *** [makefile:9: HelloJNI.h] Error 2
```

I am puzzled by the error message. Does javac recognize `../bin` as a flag? Is there some weird bug happening in Eclipse? If I try to do this in the terminal, I get the same error. I tried searching for answers, but found none.

This is my directory strcture:

```
-bin
    HelloJNI.class
-jni
    makefile
-src
    HelloJNI.java
```

---

**Edit**: Changing the javac call to

```
javac -h -classpath $CLASS_PATH $*
```

gave me the following error:

```
error: Class names, 'LASS_PATH,HelloJNI', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
```

Comment: [**You must specify a directory after `-h`** like `-h ../jni` or `-h .`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html#option-h) also you need to provide the _source_ not the _classfile_ and thus should use that for the dependency. The page you link told you this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Starting point

Looking at [the tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/javanativeinterface.html) you're following,
your question lines up with "2. Getting Started", specifically "Step 2" – compiling Java and generating a C/C++ header file.

To revisit, here's what you tried:

```
javac -h -classpath ../bin HelloJNI
```

A few points..

- The `-h` option to `javac` specifies a directory. This directory is where the generated header file should go. It requires a directory name immediately after, like this: `-h directory`. In the attempt above, it's using the `-h` option, but doesn't specify a directory. That's an issue.
- This includes `-classpath ../bin` which isn't necessary for this example. It's not a problem, but it isn't necessary to include and can be removed.
- "HelloJNI" is not an appropriate input for the compiler - you need to specify a ".java" filename

#### The fix

In the tutorial, they show this example:

```
javac -h . HelloJNI.java
```

This works because:

- They're using `-h` with "." as the directory (where "." means "current directory").
- They're compiling the .java file – "HelloJNI.java"
- Also, they're not using `-classpath`.
  That option is used to designate where to find class files for compilation (as *input* to compilation itself), but that isn't relevant for this tutorial example
  – there aren't any necessary input classes for `javac` to work.
  So, just remove `-classpath ../bin` altogether.

In the end, things should work for you if you run the command as they posted in the tutorial:

```
javac -h . HelloJNI.java
```

#### Also: JDK version differences

You didn't specify which JDK version you're using, but if you're using an older (pre-8) version of the JDK, there are
different steps to follow (namely, using `javah` in addition to `javac`).